# Title is repeated in Help and improvement queue help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, help-center, help-improvement

In the [Help and improvement queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-help-and-improvement) help page, the title is repeating. Where as the other review help pages in the [Review Queues help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-queues) doesn't have the repeated title.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: repeated title]